# Unable to create separate tables for each user with Devise and Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, devise

I am a Rails newbie and I `m creating my very first Rails App with Bootstrap and MySQL as a database.

My question is: How can I create a new table, or record,  for each new user of my app ? I made a simple test and any user can see and delete the data from another user.

My application is like a online store, so I need that each vendor can create their products (Because they need to control their own supply) and show to any user that wants to buy that product. Like a online shop.

I checked the similar questions, but I didn`t find anything related.

Now I `m running Rails 4.2.5.2, ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-darwin14], using Rubymine as IDE, and Mac OSX Yosemite as OS.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Devise + CanCanCan + Rolify to authenticate your users and assign permissions based on their individual roles i.e Admins can Create/Delete Edit or Users can only View.

Here is a [Tutorial](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify/wiki/Devise---CanCanCan---rolify-Tutorial)
On how to install and use each of these gems.